# Hyper dense muscles

Tags: creature-design, xenobiology, hard-science, biochemistry, bio-mechanics

My  organism has hyperdense muscles. This allows their type to generate enormous aerial force, some even able to cut things with their wings or generate G-force winds. What materials is their wings made of and How dense they really need to do these things ?

Comment: What materials needed would need a better explanation of what things they can cut and what forces they are producing and subject to.  What does "G-force winds" mean ?

Comment: Also worth noting that "dense muscles" are somewhat at odds with a flying creature, and "how dense they really need" is difficult to parse.  Are you asking how dense their muscles need to be?  Because muscle density is not proportional to strength.

Comment: Maybe "turbulence" is meant instead of G-force ? Remark: hard science talking biology subjects involves more than a calculation of density and tensile strength of one specific part. What about bones ? Putting this question as if it requires some calculated outcome inhibits a lot of answers. It would give more freedom for creature-design answers, if this were tagged "science-fiction" instead. Suppose the answer would be  titanium or carbon fibers (or silicones, for that matter) the *organism* would require engineering rather than evolution, to maintain structural integrity.

Answer (score 5):

[Use this material, but with much more advanced sci fi tech.](https://www.iflscience.com/technology/scientists-create-soft-and-superstrong-synthetic-muscles-for-lifelike-robots/)

> Scientists at Columbia Engineering have created a synthetic soft "muscle" that is capable of lifting over 1,000 times its own weight, overcoming what is “one of the final barriers to making lifelike robots."...

> The 3D-printable material is able to contract and expand like a real muscle yet does not require any external compressor or high voltage equipment. When it’s heated through a low electrical charge the muscle expands, and when cooled, it contracts. It consists of a silicone rubber matrix with ethanol distributed throughout in micro-bubbles, meaning it's also easy to fabricate, relatively low cost, and made of environmentally safe materials.

So, an advanced silicone rubber matrix with ethanol in it. They would need to eat sand or glass or rocks or something like that to get silicon for silicone, but otherwise they could get everything they need from nature.

Comment: Add to the fact that, at least on earth, silicon is plentiful, you got a nice rock/sand eating creature.

Comment: How would this silicone super muscle be connected to the bone ? And this is quite homogenious material, the same contraction force will be everywhere.. So when it's coiled around the bone, how would the creature prevent breaking its own legs..

Comment: Op asked us to give them their muscles, not do an in depth analysis of related tissues like bone and tendons and such and how each tissue anchors to the muscle and survives it.